In ansys, I want to export the stiffness matrix, but there is no .full file generated in my working directory
When I use ANSYS workbench and APDL, I would like to generate a stiffness matrix using the following command:
*SMAT,MatMS,D,IMPORT,FULL,file.full,STIFF
but there is no .full file generated in my working directory.
Then I used the following command to attempt generating the stiffness matrix:
/SOLU
/OUTPUT, elemstiff, txt
SOLVE

but in elemstiff.txt, I don't find the stiffness matrix:
And my version of ANSYS is 2024r2,
So how can I out the stiffness matrix in ANSYS 2024R2. Thank you in advance for your answer.
